# Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: image, browser, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

We recently started using Amazon CloudFront as CDN for images and I noticed that when I'm trying to share it via Pinterest Pin It button, there is this error in the console.

> [Error] [Report Only] Refused to load the image
>   'https://d9hblenkye2332.cloudfront.net/image.jpg' because it violates
>   the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
>   *.pinterest.com *.pinimg.com *.google.com connect.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.facebook.com www.googleadservices.com googleads.g.doubleclick.net 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that
>   'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

After doing some research, it seems that this is related to Content Security (http://content-security-policy.com), but I'm not sure what has to be done, especially when there is no setting for this in the CDN. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What is your origin server ? If this is S3 bucket, you might want to take a look at the CORS policy for this. Typical causes for such problems are the CORS. The settings for CORS is not done on the CDN itself, but on the orgin server behind this (if it is S3, then in the bucket CORS policy)

Some info is here:

Enabling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing - Amazon Simple Storage Service : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: Since I don't have access to the origin server and that there is no configuration on the CDN, I'm not sure what to do. Will probably have to contact Amazon and see what they can do.